# Get single value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code that returns me an array

```
$t=TicketType::Select('id')->where('title', $request->get('type'))->first();
dd($t);
```

this one

```
TicketType {#452 ▼
  +timestamps: false
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:1 [▶]
  #original: array:1 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

However I want just **1**,how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `eloquent` and don't need to use select query so try
this:

```
$t=TicketType::where('title', $request->get('type'))->first()->id;
```

Comment: Do you want to get Id or MainMenu?